# Python Dash update dash_table base on user input

Tags: python, plotly-dash, pandasql

So I have been trying to achieve the function that a table will automatically update based on two dcc.Input boxes. So there are two input boxes, one is minimum value and the other is maximum value. I try to update the table in the callback function update_graph_min, trying to use pandasql. But the table won't update and I cannot figure out why. Here is a snippit of my code:

```
from dash import Dash, html, dcc, callback, Output, Input, dash_table
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Output, State, Input
import pandasql as ps

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\PENGYUANZHANG\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject5\\Data\\Mantas_test.csv')
df = df.iloc[:100]

app = Dash(
    __name__,
    meta_tags=[{"name": "viewport", "content": "width=device-width, initial-scale=1"}],
)

app.title = "Hub and Spoke Dashboard"

server = app.server
app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\PENGYUANZHANG\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject5\\Data\\Mantas_test.csv')
df = df.iloc[:100]
colors = {'background': '#111111', 'text': '#7FDBFF'}
def generate_table(dataframe):
   return dash_table.DataTable(id='mantas-table',
                               data=dataframe.to_dict('records'),
                               page_size=20,
                               style_data={'color': colors['text']},
                               style_header={'color': colors['text']},
                               style_cell={'color': colors['background']}),

app.layout = html.Div(style = {'backgroundcolor': colors['background']}, children=[
    html.H1(children='Mantas transactions', style={'textAlign': 'center', 'color': colors['text'], 'fontSize': 30}),
    html.Hr(),
    "Minimum Originator Amount: ",
    dcc.Input(id='am_min', type='number', min=0, step=500, placeholder='Min Orig Amount'),
    "\n",
    "Maximum Originator Amount: ",
    dcc.Input(id='am_max', type='number', max=100000000, step=500, placeholder='Max Orig Amount'),
    html.Hr(),
    dcc.RadioItems(options=['ORIG_TRXN_ACTVY_AM', 'BENEF_TRXN_ACTVY_AM', 'SEND_TRXN_ACTVY_AM'], value='ORIG_TRXN_ACTVY_AM', id='controls-and-radio-item'),
    dash_table.DataTable(id='mantas-table', data=df.to_dict('records'), page_size=20, style_data={'color': colors['text']}, style_header={'color': colors['text']}, style_cell={'color': colors['background']}),
    dcc.Graph(figure={}, id='controls-and-graph')
])

@callback(
    Output('controls-and-graph', 'figure'),
    Input('controls-and-radio-item', 'value')
)
def update_graph_radio(col_chosen):
    fig = px.histogram(df, x='ORIG_NM', y=col_chosen, histfunc='avg')
    fig.update_layout(
        plot_bgcolor=colors['background'],
        paper_bgcolor=colors['background'],
        font_color=colors['text']
    )
    return fig

@callback(
    Output('mantas_table', 'data'),
    [Input('am_min', 'value'),
     Input('am_max', 'value')],
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def update_graph_min(am_min, am_max):
    query = "Select * from df where df.ORIG_TRXN_ACTVY_AM < " + str(am_max) + "and df.ORIG_TRXN_ACTVY_AM > " + str(am_min)
    new_df = ps.sqldf(query, locals())
    return new_df.to_dict('records')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Can anyone help me with this please

Comment: Can you try `dash_table.DataTable(id='mantas-table', data=[]` instead of `dash_table.DataTable(id='mantas-table', data=df.to_dict('records')`?

Comment: @hoatran I tried and this way the table will not show at all. Update the input box does not show the table either

Comment: Did you try to add value to input then print new_df? Is it blank or has data?

Comment: @hoatran I solved it...it is stupid lol. The id of the table has a dash in between while in my callback function it was an underscore....